# java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting PBEWithMD5AndDES

Tags: java, encryption, md5, des

I am getting the following Exception while executing my code.

Here the code snippet which causes this error

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES");
```

I have used javax-crypto.jar.

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting PBEWithMD5AndDES
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
```

My runtime is

```
C:\Documents and Settings\592635>java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_22-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 17.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

What can be the reason ? 
Please help.

Comment: Note that you should not use MD5 anymore, let alone DES. MD5 is broken and DES simply has a key size that can be brute forced in minutes.

Comment: Can you indicate your runtime environment?

Answer (score 0):

Your Oracle JRE has been configured this way or it has become corrupted. For instance, the provider that contains the required algorithm may have been removed from the list in `lib/security/java.security` in your Java JRE.

If you are not in an Oracle JRE then your runtime may not contain a provider that implements the algorithm. Note that a Java RE is not required to support `"PBEWithMD5AndDES"`, at least [not at the Java 7 level](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#impl). In that case install the Bouncy Castle or Spongy Castle libraries (according to their documentation).

Comment: Actually, PBEWithMD5AndDES is specifically mentioned in the [Cipher section](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher) of that document both for Java 7 and even [Java 6 too](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#Cipher).

Comment: How to check if my jre is configured that way ??

Comment: @OlegEstekhin And in 8 as well. So the algorithm should be available by default in the Oracle JRE. But not in others, per se. PS feel free to edit such information in...